# Python Kivy ListAdapter text wrap inside Popup

Tags: python, kivy

i've been trying for some time to wrap the text from a list and i don't know how to wrap the text of a simple Label.

I have a list of strings, and i would like to show it with a ListView inside a Popup, and wrapped

```
class SomeClass(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SomeClass, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # TextInput + ListView
        ...
        # Popup

        lv_adapter = SimpleListAdapter(data=string_list,cls=Label)
        lv = ListView(adapter=lv_adapter)
        self.popup = Popup(title='A very large title ..... ....... .... ....',
                           content=lv,size_hint=[.9,.8])

    def some_function(self, *args):
        if <some_condition>:
            self.popup.open()
```

Image of the extended Popup
http://oi60.tinypic.com/2cyh5j8.jpg

Image of the shrunken Popup
http://oi61.tinypic.com/2hg4r4m.jpg

#

SOLUTION:

I've found an alternative to wrap text inside a ListView, using a Label inside a BoxLayout, here is the code:

```
class SomeClass(Screen):

    def poplb_update(self, *args):
        self.poplb.text_size = self.popup.size

    def some_function(self):
        self.popup.open()


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SomeClass, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # Some code
        . . .

        # Popup
        self.popup = Popup(title=popupTitle,size_hint=[.9,.6])
        self.popbox = BoxLayout()
        self.poplb = Label(text=stringPopup,font_size=25,strip=True,
                           text_size=self.popup.size)
        self.popup.bind(size=self.poplb_update)
        self.popbox.add_widget(self.poplb)
        self.popup.content = self.popbox
```

Comment: I have a [blog post](http://inclem.net/2014/07/05/kivy/kivy_label_text/) about wrapping text in a Label.

Comment: Thanks, i already saw it before posting this thread. I'm going to continue trying

Comment: Then you should explain what your problem is, and why the method in that post doesn't fix it.

Comment: Is there a way to give the "cls" property of the "SimpleListAdapter" a custom Label template? I've tried and it says "not callable". I've tried also with a simple Label, and i can't get the size right of the popup, because the Label is inside the Popup. When i try to access "self.texture_size[1]" it says something like "SomeClass doesn't have that property"

Comment: Yes, it simply takes the name of the class you want to use. Again, please post an example of what you are trying.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the example is inside the code block in the first post. I have a list of strings, and i want to show each string of the list with a ListView, and what i'm trying to do, is to make a custom Label with the necessary properties to wrap each of the strings in the ListView. And this ListView is inside a Popup.